# Java selenium WebDriver- how to reload page if loading takes too long or close browser and go forward?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I work with Selenium 2.45.0 in Java. I have problem with page facebook. When page loading so long, program has stopped after 20 second and break a program.

Program has problem with find elementToBeClickable and this is end work program.

i used many commands : 
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // this is not working

```
Set<String> winSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
List<String> winList = new ArrayList<String>(winSet);
String newTab = winList.get(winList.size() - 1);
driver.switchTo().window(newTab);

sleep(1500);


try {
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
     try {
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='pagesHeaderLikeButton']/button")).click();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("This is not exist");
     }

} catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("no page");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

// when page load and close automatically after 20 second, exception dont exist and program has brake.

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
try {
    driver.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("i cant close facebook");
}


// Allow time for the Like action to go through
sleep(1000);
// Close this window and switch back to the main one

try {
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("cant back to main window");
}
```

What's is wrong with this code? 
This is not all code, but only element of code.
I use while and other stuff. 
i have problem in this moment of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public static boolean windowExists(WebDriver driver, String title,
     TestPolicy testPolicy)
{
  Iterator<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();

  while (handles.hasNext())
  {
     String handle = handles.next();
     if (handle == null)
     {
        continue;
     }
     try
     {
        WebDriver popup = driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        if (popup.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title))
        {
           return true;
        }
     }
     catch (NoSuchWindowException e)
     {
        // System.out.println("Couldn't find the window handle " +
        // handle);
     }
  }
  return false;    
}


public static void waitUntilWindowExists(final WebDriver driver,
     final String windowName, final TestPolicy testPolicy)
{
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until(new Predicate<WebDriver>()
  {
     @Override
     public boolean apply(WebDriver arg0)
     {
        return OLCommon.windowExists(driver, windowName, testPolicy);
     }
  });
}
```